# How to find out when battery stopped charging?

Tags: battery

I was wondering if it would be possible to know when (for what period, at what time) my battery stopped charging (e.g. in power outage, when I'm not around).

Is there any way to get hold of “history of charging” for my laptop ?

Comment: At least under Ubuntu, [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal) gives you a command line version.  What O/S are you using?

Comment: That link shows how to check battery status, not how to check when it stopped charging, and when it resumed.

Comment: Battery firmware does not store such time-based information.